# php pdo every second element red

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have a database and I want every second element to colored in green.

```
$sql=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM blume WHERE 1");
$i = 0;

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if ($i % 2 == 0){ echo '<div class="red">'.$row ['title'].'</div>';}
  else {echo '<div class="green">'.$row ['title'].'</div>'; 
  $i++;   
}
```

This one ist not working. I'll always get all in green, and than all in red color.

Comment: Well, you're never doing anything with `$i`, so it will always be `0`. In your `while`-loop, add something like `$i++;`.

Comment: You just need to increment `$i` on every loop iteration...

Comment: o sorry I#ve use this, but forget to write it here into code.

Comment: Why not just use CSS for this? Particularly, you can use [:nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/) to do this.

Comment: it's not only green/red. Is lot of other code there. green/red is only simplification of that.

Answer (score 1):

check this code. you need to increment $i value and you missing  close tag '}'

```
$sql=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM blume WHERE 1");
$i = 0;

 while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
if ($i % 2 == 0){ echo '<div class="red">'.$row ['title'].'</div>';}
 else {echo '<div class="green">'.$row ['title'].'</div>' };
 $i++;    
}
```

you can use also this code for your code. this is simple condition so your code will more readable

```
<?php 
$sql=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM blume WHERE 1");
$i = 0;
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'red' : 'green';
  echo '<div class="'.$class.'">'.$row ['title'].'</div>';    
  $i++;
 }
?>
```

Comment: happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up a fair bit and get the effect you want using an array of colors you toggle between:

```
$sql=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM blume WHERE 1");
$colors = array('red', 'green');
$i = 0;

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo sprintf('<div class="%s">%s</div>', $colors[$i%2], $row['title']);

  $i++;
}
```

Since `$i%2` returns either 0 or 1 then that will index one of the two elements in the array.

Comment: this 'red' and 'green' are lot more code as red and green. I've just put it simple.

Comment: @lokalinjo You can expand on this to add any necessary functionality.

Comment: actually, I've already try it as you wrote. And it works. I've put all code into variable and dann as array.